# More than a database in an app

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I create more than one database in an application?

How is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd say use local storage instead of a database on the device.

Comment: just create diff DB in SQLiteHelper class

Answer (score 1):

Just create 2 database files and 2 [database open helpers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) each opening a distinct DB file. You are not limited by the number of DBs in Android.